# Display query result and export to excel using classic asp

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp-classic, export, export-to-excel

I'm working on a small project regarding classic ASP and sql server.

I have a drop down menu where the user can enter name, last name, etc. and it will create a query based on that and create a table displaying the result.

What I want to add is the option to export to excel after the table is created. I've looked at other tutorials but they all use the simple Select * from table rather than a query based on user input.

can anyone help on this?

Comment: Why would it matter if the tutorial uses `select * from table` vs. `select * from table where MyColumn = @UserInput`? Wouldn't the technique for exporting still be the same?

Comment: well, i've got it at on button.count >1 then connect to database, generate the query, display query on table and create exportToExcel link. 

when i do the common:
<code>Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Enquiry_List.xls"</code> 

it will display the whole page rather than the table itself and i doubt i can activate it without creating another submit button (but i already have one when i'm developing the query)

does this make sense?

Comment: btw, sorry about the inline code, i'm new at this

Answer (score 0):

add

```
response.contenttype ="Application/vnd.excel"
response.addheader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelDatei.xls"
```

and the browser opens the save/open/cancel dialog...

is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my question which dealt more with how to use this code. What I ended up doing is storing the SQL query in a session variable and creating a link to a new ASP page that will connect to the database, create the Excel object, and output to it.

Comment: sql injection alert - sql injection alert